# How to show full text and wrap in menu item in angular material

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

I am trying to make a notification system, So I am using the `mat-menu` from angular material. I've increased the width of `menu-item` but the problem is that it is not showing the full content. It is only showing the text which comes in one line.

[image]

but I want to wrap the text on a new line if it exceeds that line like here

[image]

my `compontent.html`

```
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="notification"><mat-icon>add_alert</mat-icon></button>
  <mat-menu #notification="matMenu" [overlapTrigger]="false" class="my-full-width-menu">
    <button mat-menu-item style="white-space: normal">
      Learn one way to build applications with Angular and reuse your code and abilities to build
      apps for any deployment target. For web, mobile web, native mobile and native desktop.
    </button>
    <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
  </mat-menu>
```

and `CSS` is

```
.mat-menu-panel.my-full-width-menu {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

Please tell me how to do that.

Comment: is css `word-break: break-word;` what u mean?

Comment: @RamondeVries, I tried but It is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `mat-menu-item` class has static `line-height` and static `height` to `48px` that is preventing it from word wrapping.

```
::ng-deep button.mat-menu-item {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    /** set line height to desired height */
    line-height: 18px;
    /** set height to auto */
    height: auto;
    padding: 0 16px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

To set menu width, use the following.

```
::ng-deep div.mat-menu-panel {
    min-width: 112px;
      /** set width to 500px */
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 48px);
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0;
}
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzbutg?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.css

Comment: It is not showing the full text, It is only truncating the text that goes out of view.

Comment: see added stackblitz example to answer.

Comment: It works when I remove `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` from `.ts` , But if I removed this then the width will set to the default size `280px`, then how to increase width size.

Comment: see revised answer and stackblitz for menu width to `500px`

Comment: ::ng-deep is deprecated, don't use this solution