# How to insert a 'newline character' in a menu item?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, menuitem

I'm using Angular Material. I need to create a menu where one of the items consists of two large paragraphs. The text is cut off, and only the first paragraph appears.

Can anyone help? Link to the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-menu-item-newline

Thank you.

Comment: That's by design.

Comment: You can override the height css style on `.mat-menu-item` to allow it to show multiple lines. `height: auto` would work.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/54023387/9277073

Comment: Thanks for the advice and link, guys. I've managed to do it, and it's looking fine in my app. If you guys want to review the solution and agree with it, I'll mark it as the accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do it by doing two things:

- First, add the css described in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzbutg?embed=1&file=app/menu-overview-example.css:

  ::ng-deep button.mat-menu-item {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: 0;
  border: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
  /** set line height to desired height */
  line-height: 18px;
  /** set height to auto */
  height: auto;
  padding: 0 16px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  }

- Second: Instead of one button with newline characters, which are not supported in HTML, I've created two buttons, with the first having a margin-bottom of 12px to fake a new paragraph.